# What is "hrtimer: interrupt took x ns" mean? seen in dmesg

Tags: linux

What is 'hrtimer - interrupt took x ns' mean?

I see this in dmesg on Linux (RH)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It just indicates that CPU took x nano seconds to finish processing all soft-expired timers.

Comment: Does it indicate that the server is under high CPU usage? Does this message mean that we have processes waiting for the CPU to become available?

Answer (score 8):

This message is often found in cases of high CPU usage, and is an interrupt event for your CPU. For more information consider reading this: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/kernel-interrupt-overview/